# What is the sql query for this task to find first and last entry?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the sql query that will tell me how many different days the user `abc` visited the website (regardless page) and what date was the first visit and last visit?

In the following example, the user `abc` visited 3 different days, first visit on `2009-05-16` and last on `2009-05-18`

```
id  - user - page - timestamp
340 - abc - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:51:11
339 - abc - page3 - 2009-05-18 22:40:01
338 - abc - page3 - 2009-05-17 21:20:01
337 - xyz - page2 - 2009-05-18 22:06:00
336 - xyz - page1 - 2009-05-18 22:05:10
335 - abc - page3 - 2009-05-17 20:50:12
334 - abc - page3 - 2009-05-16 12:10:01
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So To get this, first get min(timestamp) to get first visit
max(timestamp) to get Last visit
and count(distinct(date(timestamp))) to get total distinct days visited

```
SELECT min(date(timestamp1)) as FirstVisit, max(date(timestamp1)) as LastVisit, count(distinct(date(timestamp1))) as distinctDays from yourtablename
```

Edit:- timestamp is reserved keyword in mysql. So changed it timestamp1

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
Select count(*) as timeVisited, min(timestamp) firstvisit, max(timestamp) last
From yourtablename 
Where user='abc'
```

Comment: This will not give distinct date but total count of visit.

Comment: hi, this counts the number of pages of all dates. However, I want to know how many unique days he visited the website.

Comment: Also timestamp is reserved keyword in mysql

Comment: I misunderstood the question maybe you should use sub queries but in this case the performance will be affected. @Naruto thanks for mentioning the timestamp thing I tried to use the same column naming

Answer (score 0):

Very crude handling of the timestamp (you could use more robust date functions), but here is the idea :

```
SELECT user,COUNT(*) as "# visits",MIN(LEFT(timestamp,10)) as "Oldest visit",MAX(LEFT(timestamp,10)) as "Most recent visit"
FROM your_table
group by
user, LEFT(timestamp,10)
```

Comment: No, just that you could handle the timestamp using date functions instead of a "LEFT".

Comment: You mean like `year(\`timestamp\`)` instead of `LEFT(\`timestamp\`,4)`?

Comment: thank you, however this shows only the year (2016). how to also show month and day?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Use `date(\`timestamp\`)`.

Comment: My bad, I extended the the LEFTs from 4 to 10 :)